# modified gram schmidt...

Tags: linear-algebra

So I understand that the effective formula for the orthogonal basis of a matrix is the same in both modified and classical Gram Schmidt algorithm. Can someone explain whats the numerical instability that arises with classical gram schmidt? and how does modified solve it.

Comment: this sounds like classic numeric linear algebra textbook stuff. please have a look at: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/asna/index.php

Comment: Type "numerical instability gram-schmidt" into Google and you get plenty of well-informed responses.  Even YouTube video demonstrations.  

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, because of rounding off the numbers - vectors loose their orthoginality in non-modified version. Wikipedia article about Gram-Schmidt explains the modification.